# Only Getting 30 Days of Data on Yahoo Historical API

Tags: php, mysql, api, yahoo-api

I'm trying to access the historic data on Yahoo's api (with a PHP/Mysql implementation) using this url as an example:

```
$url = http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=INTC&c=2014&f=2015&a=0&d=0&b=1&e=1&g=d&ignore=.csv
```

This is the code I used to access it:

```
$filesize = 2000;
$handle = fopen($url, "r");
$raw_quote_data = fread($handle, $filesize);
echo $raw_quote_data;
fclose($handle);
```

The echo statement is for error checking, to make sure that I'm getting all the data before I store it in my database. However, the $raw_quote_data being returned only has data for the last 30 days of the time range inputted. Because the date range I inputted was from January 1, 2014 to January 1, 2015, it should return 365 days of data. So what am I doing wrong? Where is the rest of the data going?

The first thing I tried, of course, was changing the filesize, which has zero effect on the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `file_get_contents()` instead.

```
$raw_quote_data =  file_get_contents($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You are requesting a 15kb file and only reading in 2000 bytes.**  Also note that when you manually read from the buffer, all the data might not have arrived yet.  That is why "it made no difference."

Try this instead:

```
set_time_limit(0);
$file = @fopen($file_path,"rb");
while(!feof($file))
{
    print(@fread($file, 1024*8));
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
```

**See [this article](http://www.media-division.com/the-right-way-to-handle-file-downloads-in-php/) for more information.**

Alternatively **[`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)** may be a simpler approach.